# UDP packets are recieved only once and repeat in Loop, How to recieve in loop in real time changing data?

Tags: python, udp

I am sending real time changing data of few variables from Matlab function via Simulink function M = fcn(time). I have written a code i will share below in Raspberry pi which works ok when i recieve the packet once. But when i move 
 `list = [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]`
  this line in While loop , it conitously recieve data , but only take the initial values. It does not Change to new value. 
I have tried to solve it in matlab , I have changed the value of time, previously it was : 
`if ((time >= 1) && (time < 5 ))`
new 
`if ((time >= 1* 0.001 ) && (time < 5 * 0.002))`

```
BUFFER_SIZE=1024
try:
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print ('socket created')
except socket.error:
    print ('failed to creat socket.')
    sys.exit


try:
    sock.bind((IP, PORT))
    print ('sockesimulink codersimulink code bind')

except socket.error:
    print ('bind failed.') 
    sys.exit()

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    now = datetime.now()
    data, addr=sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
    timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
    print("timestamp =", timestamp)
    l=len(data);
    print('length');
    print(l);
    list = [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]
    for x in list:
        print(int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='little')/10);
```

When i have increased the time Speed of matlab Code to 0.001 seconds then the python Code in Raspberry detects each Change in value. 
I want to slow down the Speed of python so it takes values per second and should not stop in initial value. I have tried Sleep , but it delays only packet , but does not Change the value to new one in the second packet.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would return the same data repeatedly.

Comment: It returns 0.0 for change and keeps at 0.0 for all.

Comment: Try printing `data` itself rather than the result, to see if it's really the same.

Comment: yes tried it , ist in Hex Format Zeros , but Problem is solved ist not a mistake in this Code of python , you are Right. it was matlab Code fault